# No Foreign Keys exception with Ormlite Join

Tags: join, foreign-keys, ormlite

I'm having problems getting a join to work, the two table definitions are as follows:

```
public class Student { 
    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = true, columnName = STUDENT_INSTANCE_COLLECTION_NAME)
    private ForeignCollection<StudentInstance> studentInstances;

    ...
}

public class StudentInstance {
    public static final String STUDENT_ID_COLUMN = "student_id";
    public static final String REGISTER_ID_COLUMN = "register_id";

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true)
    private Student student;

    @DatabaseField(canBeNull = false, foreign = true)
    private Register register;

   ...

}
```

Activity code:

```
public List<Student> getStudents( int registerId ) {
    QueryBuilder<StudentInstance, Integer> studentInstanceQb =  studentInstanceDao.getDAO().queryBuilder();
    studentInstanceQb.where().eq(StudentInstance.REGISTER_ID_COLUMN, registerId);
    QueryBuilder<Student, Integer> studentQb =  getDAO().queryBuilder();    
    studentQb.join(studentInstanceQb).query();
}
```

and when I run the code I get the exception:

> Error on getStudents: java.sql.SQLException: Could not find a foreign
>   class com.beardedhen.roster.db.entity.Student field in class
>   com.beardedhen.roster.db.entity.StudentInstance or vice versa

It's probably a silly error but I've hit a complete brick wall with it.

Thanks for any help,

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the QueryBuilder. matchJoinedFields(), where the exception came from. You will see how current (4.42) implementation checks the tables and looks for connected columns for the join.